# Completely disable audio jack as media output

Tags: android, audio, output

I bought 3.5 dust plug jack and I'm using its button. but android is considering it as a headphone and always routing the audio to it not the phone speakers nor the Bluetooth. I need to completely disable it as a media output. Please advise or guide where to ask. StackOverflow, superuser. XDA, Android central or Reddit. My phone is rooted and ready for any solution.

Comment: This is not programmers question... So, it should be asked at least not here or changed to programmers side... you can try this place: https://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you, I asked their on android.stackoverflow